# How to get innerHTML of this element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, this, innerhtml

Pretty simple question. I have an element (a tag) which has an onclick to call a javascript function. Amoung other things, I want this function to echo the innerHTML of the element that called it. So, in this case, the innerHTML of the atag.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<element onClick="alert(this.innerHTML);"> ... </element>
```

Comment: Nice try, but It kind of dismisses the fact that I said call a javascript function

Comment: "It works" isn't enough. The reason that went out of fashion is because it is poor practise.

Comment: `this.innerHTML` is the important part, so it's a valid answer.

Comment: +1 Nothing wrong with inline handlers. They can be very useful, and solve or simplify some problems.

Comment: +1 for an excellently efficient suggestion that doesn't require you to build a function outside of the element to call to reference back to the element itself to handle its own content

Answer (score 3):

markup:

```
<element id="foo"> ... </element>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById('foo').addEventListener('click', fn);

function fn(){ alert(this.innerHTML); }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g7Bau/2/

The important thing to note here, which essentially answers your question, is that the event listener when called has binds `this` to the DOM node that caused the event to fire. So we can use `this` in the function and it's generic. You could add another element, and bind a click listener also using `fn` and the one function would work for both elements.

Comment: @Raynos, you're right. The trend in all major browsers is to make it optional though, as per the HTML5 spec. This clearly isn't a cross-browser solution, since <IE9 this won't even work...